# Unable to access Push service dashboard on Bluemix

Tags: push-notification, push, ibm-cloud

When trying to access the Push service dashboard I got this error:

```
 Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.mbaas.ui.BackendUtility.getJSONResponse:-1' 
 javax.servlet.ServletException: UIBACK108E: Got unsuccessful response from 'https://mccp.ng.bluemix.net/login/rolecheck'. The response status was 400 Bad Request. The response body was: "{"error":"bad_request","error_description":"Parameters role and space_guid are required"}". 
 at com.ibm.mbaas.ui.BackendUtility.getJSONResponse(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.mbaas.ui.BackendUtility.checkRole(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.mbaas.ui.security.UAACallBackServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
 at [internal classes]
```

Tested in different browsers with same results.

Is this a know issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was maintenance being completed on US-South region over the last 24 hours. Here is the support notice:

> IBM Bluemix Platform maintenance US-SOUTH region June 2 10:00 PM EDT
>   Starting at 10pm US EST Tuesday June 2, and lasting approximately 24
>   hours, there will be a maintenance update rolling out across the
>   Bluemix platform US-South region. During this time, you may experience
>   temporary errors logging in to Bluemix, or managing applications
>   (starting, staging, etc.). If this happens, please retry the operation
>   later. Latest status will be available at
>   https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status throughout the
>   upgrade. Existing applications will see a brief restart of instances,
>   with near continuous availability expected.
>
> Update: This maintenance is complete. 
>   Updated:  Jun 3, 2015 10:27 AM
>   UTC-0400 Starts:  Jun 2, 2015 10:00 PM UTC-0400 Ends: Jun 3, 2015 10:00
>   AM UTC-0400 Category: Bluemix Platform Region(s): us-south

If your application was created during this time can you please delete and recreate this instance to see if this solves the issue.

You can find more information on Bluemix maintenance here:
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Comment: It worked after deleting the service and bound a new service instance to my app